# Image not showing up on Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a portfolio website, and I'm trying to make logo images show up, but they're not showing up.

Originally, I had the content in the `this.state` in HomePage.js, but I decided it would be neater to put it in a different file. The images showed up when they were in HomePage.js.

## Relevant Code

**HomePageContent.js**

```
// Image import statements
import Image1 from '../img/Image1.jpg';
import Image2 from '../img/Image2.jpg';

let HomePageContent = {
  jobs: [{
    logo: {Image1},
    companyName: 'Company1' ,
    title: 'Job1',
    startMonth: 'November 2019',
    endMonth: 'Present',
    location: 'Location1',
    desc: 'Placeholder',
    id: 1
  }, {
    logo: {Image2},
    companyName: 'Company2',
    title: 'Job2',
    startMonth: 'June 2018',
    endMonth: 'May 2019',
    location: 'Location2',
    desc: 'Placeholder',
    id: 2
  }]};

export default HomePageContent;
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React from 'react';

// Component import statements
import JobsList from '../components/JobsList.js';

// Content import Statements
import HomePageContent from '../content/JobsContent.js';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = HomePageContent;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h4>Here's what I've done</h4>
        <JobsList jobs={this.state.jobs}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

**JobsList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Jobs from "./Jobs";

function JobsList(props) {
  return (
    <div className="JobsList">
      {props.jobs.map(j =>
        <Jobs logo={j.logo}
          companyName={j.companyName}
          title={j.title}
          startMonth={j.startMonth}
          endMonth={j.endMonth}
          location={j.location}
          desc={j.desc}key={j.id}/>
      )}
     </div> 
  ); 
} 

export default JobsList;
```

**Jobs.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import '../css/Experience.css';

function Jobs(props) {
  console.log(props.name);
    return (
      <div className='exp-container'>
        <img src={props.logo} alt='Logo' />
        <div className='content'>
          <div>{props.companyName}</div>
          <div>{props.title}</div>
          <div>{props.startMonth} - {props.endMonth}</div>
          <div>{props.location}</div>
          <div><p>{props.desc}</p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Jobs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <img src={props.logo} alt='Logo' />
> ```

You are trying to read the image from the `logo` property. (Aside: [Your alt text isn't useful](https://htmlhelp.com/feature/art3.htm)).

> ```
> logo: {Image1},
> ```

… but the value of the `logo` property **isn't an image**. It is another object. That object has a property named `Image1` and the **value** of that property is an image.

---

**Don't create an extra object**; just assign the image to the `logo` property:

```
logo: Image1,
```